# Gradient descent implementation is not working in Julia

Tags: julia, gradient-descent

I am trying to Implement **gradient Descent** algorithm from scratch to find the slope and intercept value for my linear fit line.

Using the package and calculating slope and intercept, I get slope = 0.04 and intercept = 7.2 but when I use my gradient descent algorithm for the same problem, I get slope and intercept both values = (-infinity,-infinity)

Here is my code

```
x= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,141,5,16,17,18,19,20]
y=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,141,5,16,17,18,19,20,21]    

function GradientDescent()
   m=0
   c=0
   for i=1:10000
      for k=1:length(x)
         Yp = m*x[k] + c   
         E = y[k]-Yp             #error in predicted value

         dm = 2*E*(-x[k])    # partial derivation of cost function w.r.t slope(m)
         dc = 2*E*(-1)       # partial derivate of cost function w.r.t. Intercept(c)
         m = m + (dm * 0.001)
         c = c + (dc * 0.001)
      end
   end
   return m,c
end

Values  = GradientDescent()   # after running values = (-inf,-inf)
```

Comment: It's impossible to answer without values for x and Y

Comment: Also, I can't see if you've defined the variables outside the for loop. Otherwise they stop existing when the for loop returns.

Comment: X and  Y both are arrays of length 200 and none of them are zero or contains any missing value. I have defined all the variables outside for  loop. I have just shared the main code snippet here, if you want i can share my entire code too

Comment: Yes - if you don't want to share your data you can repeat with random data. But it's almost impossible to give feedback unless I can copy your grey box to the terminal and recover the problem without having to do anything else

Comment: Hey, Look i have updated my post with complete code snippet

Comment: Changing the sign of the summation in m and c seem to ensure converge in your example. But I have not checked your math.

Comment: You should post that as an answer @mdavezac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not done the math, but instead wrote the tests. It seems you got a sign error when assigning m and c.

Also, writing the tests really helps, and Julia makes it simple :)

```
function GradientDescent(x, y)
   m=0.0
   c=0.0
   for i=1:10000
      for k=1:length(x)                       
        Yp = m*x[k] + c   
        E = y[k]-Yp
        dm = 2*E*(-x[k])
        dc = 2*E*(-1)

        m = m - (dm * 0.001)
        c = c - (dc * 0.001)
       end
   end
   return m,c
end

using Base.Test

@testset "gradient descent" begin
    @testset "slope $slope" for slope in [0, 1, 2]
        @testset "intercept for $intercept" for intercept in [0, 1, 2]
            x = 1:20
            y = broadcast(x -> slope * x + intercept, x)

            computed_slope, computed_intercept = GradientDescent(x, y)
            @test slope ≈ computed_slope atol=1e-8
            @test intercept ≈ computed_intercept atol=1e-8
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't get your exact numbers, but this is close. Perhaps it helps?

```
                                        # 141 ?  
datax = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,141,5,16,17,18,19,20]
datay = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,141,5,16,17,18,19,20,21]

function gradientdescent() 
    m = 0
    b = 0
    learning_rate = 0.00001
    for n in 1:10000
        for i in 1:length(datay)
            x = datax[i]
            y = datay[i]
            guess = m * x + b
            error = y - guess
            dm = 2error * x
            dc = 2error
            m += dm * learning_rate
            b += dc * learning_rate
        end
    end 
    return m, b
end

gradientdescent()

(-0.04, 17.35)
```

It seems that adjusting the learning rate is critical...

Comment: Is there any way that i can determine what could be the good learning rate

Comment: No idea, but hopefully this would be part of the material for your course...? (I just looked it up on google...) Perhaps an expert will be along later... :)

Comment: Cool ! I tried adjusting learning rate and now it stops giving infinity as my value but still, the output value varies largely from expected value! But thanks for your efforts and time